# How do I install, update, and remove apps for multiple devices in the Google Play online store?

Tags: google-play-store, multiple-devices

I've got several Android devices. I like to use the online Play store to manage installs because it's much faster than doing so through each device. However, I do not see a way to determine which apps are installed on which device without clicking through the following links, **once per app**:

> Apps → My Apps → [specific app] → Installed → Choose a Device

How do I quickly do the following, without going through the process above?

1. Review per device installations.
2. Select apps for installation, update, or removal, per device.

Comment: I used to use the web interface to update apps on all my devices then Google updated the Play store and I haven't figured a way to do this since. It seems like they really want you to do updates via the device instead of the web.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Google play Web app doesn't allow you to the following things:

- Update your current apps (It can only be done from your devices)
- See a list of apps install in a specific devices (It only tallies all of the apps you ever downloaded into one list)
- Remove any devices which were previously added to your Google account

Hopefully we can raise awareness through this question so that Google finds that enough people will like a lot more functionality from the web app. It is sometimes very functional specially if you work in a computer all day.